# Following symlinks with find to return the file the symlink is pointing to, not the symlink itself

Tags: bash, macos, find

I use usually use tmutil to control Timemachine instead of the GUI, which has some deficiencies to make it appealable to the masses.  I tend to have a lot drives attached to my iMac, at this moment I have 11 with twenty total mounted partitions, but the drives and paritions change as I work on/with them.  Sometimes many at a time.

I wrote a one-liner with the goal to report on the exclusion status of all drives in the /Volumes/ directory and an alias to it for simple reuse.  `alias tmutilvol="find /Volumes/ -maxdepth 1 -exec tmutil isexcluded {} \;"` It works, well mostly.  The typical output looks this is,

```
[Included]    /Volumes
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Backup-Lion
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Backups
[Excluded]    /Volumes/chris
[Excluded]    /Volumes/El Capitan Temp Holding
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Font
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Hades
[Excluded]    /Volumes/iMac Bad
[Excluded]    /Volumes/iMac Clone
[Excluded]    /Volumes/iMac Clone New
[Excluded]    /Volumes/iMac ElCap
[Excluded]    /Volumes/iMac HD
[Excluded]    /Volumes/iMac HD New
[Excluded]    /Volumes/iMac HS Clone
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Macintosh HD Clone 1
[Excluded]    /Volumes/maclaptop
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Old Laptop
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Old-Timemachine-Garnet
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Old-Timemachine-Lion
[Excluded]    /Volumes/TEMPORARY
[Excluded]    /Volumes/Time Machine Mirror
```

The problem is `/Volumes/iMac HD`.  This is not the actual drive, it is a symlink to it.

```
drwxr-xr-x   33 chris  staff  1190 Jan 17 12:31 Backup-Lion
drwxrwxr-x   20 chris  staff   748 Nov 11 22:03 Backups
drwxrwxr-x  107 chris  staff  3706 Nov 13 16:26 El Capitan Temp Holding
drwxrwxr-x   82 chris  staff  2856 Jan 19 16:07 Font
drwxr-xr-x  260 chris  staff  8908 Jan 22 11:51 Hades
drwxr-xr-x@  41 chris  staff  1462 Nov 11 22:03 Macintosh HD Clone 1
drwxr-xr-x   24 chris  staff   884 Nov 11 22:03 Old Laptop
drwxr-xr-x    6 chris  staff   272 Jan 17 12:31 Old-Timemachine-Garnet
drwxrwxr-x@  20 chris  staff   748 Jan 19 14:49 Old-Timemachine-Lion
drwxr-xr-x   20 chris  staff   748 Jan 22 11:54 TEMPORARY
drwxr-xr-x   12 chris  staff   476 Jan 23 01:30 Time Machine Mirror
drwx------@   6 chris  staff   272 Jan 16 16:18 chris
drwxrwxrwx   36 chris  staff  1292 Jan 19 00:15 iMac Bad
drwxrwxrwx   29 chris  staff  1054 Nov 13 16:26 iMac Clone
drwxr-xr-x    6 chris  staff   272 Jan 17 16:05 iMac Clone New
drwxr-xr-x   30 chris  staff  1088 Jan 16 17:31 iMac ElCap
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel     1 Jan 16 20:34 iMac HD -> /
drwxr-xr-x    6 chris  staff   272 Jan 17 16:05 iMac HD New
drwxrwxr-x   26 root   wheel   952 Nov 13 16:26 iMac HS Clone
drwxrwxrwx   40 chris  staff  1428 Jan 19 15:40 maclaptop
```

The result of `tmutil isexcluded` is actually for the symlink and not "/"

```
Kaze:~ chris$ tmutil isexcluded /
[Included]    /
```

I want to know if there is a way to get find to follow and pass in the destination of the symlink.  I read the find man page and about the -L option and thought that would do it and it does not.  Some digging on stackexchange https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31114/find-usage-with-l explained why it doesn't work.  What I have not been able to find is any clue as to how I might do what want and keep a simple one-liner or if I am going to have to write a function for this and deal with symlinks in some convoluted way.

I am hoping that someone with a lot more knowledge of CLI and bash than I might know how to do what I want simply.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on http://apple.stackexchange.com OR http://SuperUser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Comment: Hmm.  Shell scripting is programming as defined for StackOverflow is it not?   Just at the number of tags for shell scripting languages and even shell commands, such as find.  And the way I see it this is a question about shell scripting, and using find in particular to pass in arguments to another command, macos' tmutil with the problem of the symlinks.   I will read the site links you posted to try and understand why you see it as not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.  :-/

Comment: Just MHO. I'll be perfectly happy for you if someone answers your Q, but basically a `find` Q is using an existing program, and seems more like a SuperUser.com, or maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com problem. Something you should be able to find by purusing `man find`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
readlink "/Volumes/iMac HD"
```

one liner for mac:

```
find /Volumes  -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'N="{}"; L=`readlink "{}"`; tmutil isexcluded "${L:-$N}"' \;
```

Explanation:

have to use two variables, `$L` for readlink output, `$N` for original name.
`${L:-$N}` basically just output `$L` if its not empty, else output `$N`

Note that I have to prefix $L with "`/Volumes/`" as MacOS's readlink does not output the absolute path. Linux "`readlink -f`" solves this issue.

Comment: Well I am aware that readlink will return the correct path (as will PWD -P if in the the /iMac HD if I have cd to that directly first).  I don't know how though to use either method to work in my script.  In macOS readlink returns nothing if the input isn't a link so I could only use it in a conditional.  But that doesn't sound like a simple one-liner anymore.  Ideas?

Comment: @CKnight, edited my original post. that's a one liner.

Comment: I see what you are saying now.  Now it just is going to be figuring out how to quote it right so that the spaces in most of the volumes names are ignored.  A portion of the output I get is: `bash: HD: command not found
[Included]    /Volumes
bash: HD: command not found
[Included]    /Volumes
bash: HS: command not found
[Included]    /Volumes
bash: HD: command not found
[Included]    /Volumes
bash: Laptop: command not found
[Included]    /Volumes
[Included]    /Volumes
[Included]    /Volumes
Machine: Can't find any plists for Machine
[Included]    /Volumes`

Comment: That formatted wrong, not sure how to fix it it though in a comment.

Comment: Actually it is not working for even the volumes without spaces in their names.

Comment: `find /Volumes/ -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'N={}; L=/Volumes/ readlink "{}"; tmutil isexcluded "${L:-$N}"' \;`  Works with single word volume names, removing the backticks fixed that issue.  Multiple word volume names still broken though.  I'm sure it is a quoting issue.  Trying to figure it out.

Comment: `find /Volumes/ -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'N="{}" ; L=/Volumes/ readlink "{}"; tmutil isexcluded "${L:-$N}"' \;'  Fixes the multi-word volume names.  I will have to modify the condition though when it is a symlink though as it only prints the absolute path and isn't passing it into tmutil.

Comment: Hmm.  Everything is good except the symlink.  The output for it is `[Included]    /Volumes`  should be `[Included] /`

Comment: `find /Volumes  -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'N="{}"; L=`readlink "{}"`; tmutil isexcluded "${L:-$N}"' \;`  Works as expected.  I thought I had tried this before. UPDATE: Actually,  I did not notice at first, the "/" is removed from Volumes.  Monty, thank you so much!!

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future, the working version is `find /Volumes  -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'N="{}"; L=`readlink "{}"`; tmutil isexcluded "${L:-$N}"' \;'  .  Thanks again, Monty!

Comment: Np. Yeah. I missed to correct the prefix. Fixed now.

Comment: Fyi. Your should add / if the final target path is a subdir... readlink doesnt add /  , i.e: /vol/x -> /tmp,  readlink /vol/x only returns tmp

Comment: Actually... if the target path resides in the same dir.  I don't know why Mac's readlink can't resolve this.

`cd /Volumes;  
mkdir x;  
ln -s x y;  
readlink y # only returns x;  readlink /Volumes/y # same thing `

Comment: Well, that is yet another annoyance with Apple's implementation of readlink it seems.  Fortunately I don't cd to Volumes much so it doesn't look like it will cause me problems for this script you helped me with.  Could always modify it though to cd out of Volumes, if in it, prior to running the script then I guess cd back to Volumes to be nice.